# countably locally finite and locally finite covers

Tags: general-topology, paracompactness

[image]

I am trying to understand the above proof. My problem is that I fail to understand why we need to
construct the neighborhood $W_1\cap...\cap W_n\cap H_x$ of $x$ that interescts with finite many of $\mathcal V$. Because both $W_1\cap...\cap W_n$ and $H_x$ seem to be neighborhoods of $x$ that interescts with finite many of $\mathcal V$.

Comment: My note [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/03.pdf) has the same proof in the $(2)\implies (3)$ step. Notation slightly different but another write-up might help. $V_i$ should be $O_i$ though I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, you seem to use the same prove here with $V$ instead of $H_x$ and $N_i$ instead of $W_i$.

Comment: Yes, it's the original and standard proof (by E. Michael) for this fact. Proofs are the same in all texts that I know at least.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, but why did we consider the interesction. When $V$ is enough.

Comment: $V$ (not defined in your proof) is not enough. $W$ achieves a best of both worlds situation.

Comment: Munkres' text has a picture representation of this same proof IIRC. Maybe that'll help too.

Comment: No picture but yet another copy of the same proof in section 41, 1 to 2. Yet other notation, but quite clear IMHO.

Comment: The picture of the statement of the lemma and the picture of the proof (bad practice to use a picture BTW) seem to come from two different texts. Which ones? Out of curiosity.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5357/Beamer-Proofs/Proofs-Munkres-41-print.pdf and Foundations of General Topology by William J. Pervin and Ralph P. Boas

Comment: And why do you ask about the identical proof in the latter, compared to the one in the digital Munkres copy?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I tried to read different versions of the proof to understand it. But then the idea was made clear to me by your answer.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, There are some directions of the proof that authors including yourself have not proved because the proof is clear. Could you please check whether my proof is correct? https://i.imgur.com/TW86kF9.png

Comment: Yes those are truly trivial: an open cover is a cover (we just “forget” openness) and a locally finite cover is $\sigma$-locally finite because one family is a countable union too. Note that regularity is irrelevant for these steps. IIRC this is used to from a loc finite *closed* refinement to a loc finite *open* refinement (ie paracompact).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why $H_x \in \mathcal{H}_n$ would intersect only finitely many members of $\mathcal{V}$. It does not intersect any $V_H$ for $H$ with *higher* minimal index and we want to preserve that. But we *also* have to take care of the first $n$ many $\mathcal{H}_n$, so taking a $W_i$ for each $i$ smaller or equal takes care of that and intersecting with $H_x$ (making it smaller) adds the property we don't intersect larger indexed $V_H$.. Neither is enough by itself but the intersection achieves both, similar to taking the minimum of some finitely many $\delta$'s in some metric continuity proofs.

Comment: The fact that we have a countable union of $\mathcal H_n$ is essential: the index set is well-ordered (so the minimal index is well-defined) and any index has *finitely* many predecessors left to take care of (using *finite* intersections of neighbourhoods). Fun to realise perhaps.